# R - Convert NA to NaN

Tags: r

I have three columns in a data frame that I want to average together. The problem is, in one of the columns, some spaces read "NA". The data set I'm working with is quite large, but I'll simplify it with the below example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(2,3,4,5)
c <- c(3,NA,NA,6)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
df$mean <- (df$a + df$b + df$c)/3
df

  a b  c mean
1 1 2  3    2
2 2 3 NA   NA
3 3 4 NA   NA
4 4 5  6    5
```

I would like to format `df$c` so that the `NA`'s are replaced with something innocuous, like `NaN`, or any other value that would be ignored by the average operation while still holding a place in the data frame. If there would be another way to get the `NA`'s in column C ignored, I'd be happy.

Comment: How about `df[is.na(df)] <- NaN`?

Comment: Note that `df[is.na(df)] <- NaN` will be ignored by the average operation. It will return `NaN`.

Comment: I don't know that `NaN` is "innocuous" from mean's perspective.  `mean(c(1, NaN))` returns `NaN`. How to handle missing data for numeric calculations can be a tricky stats question, but assuming you just want to ignore it, I think the `na.rm` parameter is the way to go

Comment: Yes, `na.rm` is the most relevent option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would say `apply` mean across cols, and specify to mean that it should ignore `NA`

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(2,3,4,5)
c <- c(3,NA,NA,6)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
df$mean <- apply(df, 1, mean, na.rm = T)
```

`df` is now

```
a b  c mean
1 2  3  2.0
2 3 NA  2.5
3 4 NA  3.5
4 5  6  5.0
```

**edit** To accommodate larger datasets with columns you may wish to exclude from the average...

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(2,3,4,5)
c <- c(3,NA,NA,6) 
d <- c('excluded', 'from', 'the', 'average')
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

df$mean <- apply(df[, c('a', 'b', 'c')], 1, mean, na.rm = T)
```

Comment: Alternatively, `df$mean = rowMeans(df, na.rm = T)`

Comment: I'm with @Gregor, use a vectorized function whenever possible. And when none's available, use `[sl]apply()`. Never `apply()` on data frames.

Comment: @AkselA `[sl]apply` are good for applying functions to data frame columns, but not rows. For functions of rows, it's usually best to convert to `matrix`, which is done automatically by `apply`, `rowMean`, `rowSums`, etc.

Comment: @Gregor: I know, but if you're applying a function to the rows you're probably already using a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`, you can also try

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, mean := rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = c("a", "b", "c")]
```